# How to append and alter data in specific file locations

Tags: java, file, io, text-files

Good evening Stack Overflow! I am working on a project that resembles Windows Access Control Lists, and have run into an issue. I need to use files to keep track of who is in what group, so for instance, in my file, I want to have have this:

- Administrators: admin, mike
- Users: admin, mike, sarah, eric
- Accounting: sarah, eric

I've been simply appending data onto the list, so it would be more like this:

- Administrators: admin
- Administrators: mike

I also need to be able to add things out of order, so for instance, if I added Admin to Admins, Sarah to Accounting, then Mike to Admins, is there a way to keep all of the data in order?

I was wondering how to solve this problem, to append data to specific locations so that it doesn't look like a train wreck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append data directly into the file. You can read it all and change insert data into specific positions, using `RandomAccessFile`. Here is a nice tutorial on how to do so: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html

Below is how you insert thing in the middle of a file that is loaded in memory:

```
// open file for reading and writing
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("c:\\data\\file.txt", "rw");

// go to a certain position
file.seek(200);
// write hello world in ths position
file.write("Hello World".getBytes());

// close file - this should be done in the finally clause
file.close();
```

However, I would not follow this approach. Why don't you put everything in CSV files, read them using Java, put the content into a list, do whatever inserts, deletes and sorting you wish (sorting is alredy there for Strings), and then save the files into the the file system again?

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read CSV files, and below is an example:

```
... import java.util.*;

public class ParseCSV {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      //csv file containing data
      String strFile = "MyCSvFile.csv";
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
      String [] nextLine;
      // list holding all elements - they can be later be maniulated
      List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
      while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length;i++) {
            elements.add(nextLine[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Following this approach, then in order to insert elements in the middle, or in the end of the list is a matter of using the data structure appropriately, and finally writing them to disk, alo using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) if you wish.